# Javascript syntax for accessing elements of associative arrays within arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I can not work out the javascript syntax to access elements of the following, which has been stringify'd after being returned as JSON from php/mysql.

`vehs` contains

```
[[{"vehID":"8","vehGrpType":"CAR","vehSubGrp":"Alfa Romeo","vehTitle":"Alfa Romeo 6C","vehPeriod":"","vehDescrip":"","vehNotes":"","vehGallery":"0","vehGallPath":"","vehGallImgs":""}],[{"vehID":"9","vehGrpType":"CAR","vehSubGrp":"Alfa Romeo","vehTitle":"Alfa Romeo 75 (1985-92)","vehPeriod":"","vehDescrip":"","vehNotes":"","vehGallery":"0","vehGallPath":"","vehGallImgs":""}],[{"vehID":"10","vehGrpType":"CAR","vehSubGrp":"Alfa Romeo","vehTitle":"Alfa Romeo GTV (1995-2000) and Spider (1995-2006)","vehPeriod":"","vehDescrip":"","vehNotes":"","vehGallery":"0","vehGallPath":"","vehGallImgs":""}]]
```

I am trying

```
    for (var veh in vehs) {
        $('#selectDIV').append(veh['vehTitle'] + '<br>');
    }
```

But all I get is the numerics 0, 1 and 2, which I assume are the indexes of the three entries.

I have misunderstood something along the way, about associative arrays within array elements.
So I am a bit stuck and am not knowledgeable enough to know what combination to try next.

Any help appreciated, as I am sure it is very straightforward.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The associative array is not an element of the main array.
The main array is composed of arrays, which only contain the associative array. Refer to it using `[0]`.

Also, since `vehs` is an array, I recommend to use a for`(;;)` loop to loop through it, so that user-defined prototype methods are not inherit.
For performance reasons, I recommend to append the string at last.

```
var string = [];
for (var i=0; i<vehs.length; i++) {
    var veh = vehs[i];
    string.push(veh[0]['vehTitle'] + '<br>');;
}
$('#selectDIV').append(string.join(''));
```

### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NgmFP/

Comment: Curses - I had high hopes for your solution, but it is giving me `undefined`.

Comment: @mcl My code is working fine, see this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NgmFP/. Did you implement it wrongly?

Comment: Many thanks.  I can see yours works and I do not know why mine does not - I just changed the line in my original loop.  I can appreciate the build string, with one append is quicker.  I hope I can do this for all the fields.  I have to admit I have no knowledge of the issue of `;;`.  Thanks again at least I can make some progress and I have learned a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

It's a 2 dimensional array. You have 3 array elements, each one containing one object.

```
for (var index in vehs) {
    $('#selectDIV').append(vehs[index][0]['vehTitle'] + '<br>');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Reformatted, your array looks like this:

```
vehs = [[{
    "vehID": "8",
    "vehGrpType": "CAR",
    "vehSubGrp": "Alfa Romeo",
    "vehTitle": "Alfa Romeo 6C",
    "vehPeriod": "",
    "vehDescrip": "",
    "vehNotes": "",
    "vehGallery": "0",
    "vehGallPath": "",
    "vehGallImgs": ""
}], [{
    "vehID": "9",
    "vehGrpType": "CAR",
    "vehSubGrp": "Alfa Romeo",
    "vehTitle": "Alfa Romeo 75 (1985-92)",
    "vehPeriod": "",
    "vehDescrip": "",
    "vehNotes": "",
    "vehGallery": "0",
    "vehGallPath": "",
    "vehGallImgs": ""
}], [{
    "vehID": "10",
    "vehGrpType": "CAR",
    "vehSubGrp": "Alfa Romeo",
    "vehTitle": "Alfa Romeo GTV (1995-2000) and Spider (1995-2006)",
    "vehPeriod": "",
    "vehDescrip": "",
    "vehNotes": "",
    "vehGallery": "0",
    "vehGallPath": "",
    "vehGallImgs": ""
}]]
```

You can simplify it by getting rid of extra inner arrays:

```
objects = $(vehs).map([].pop)
```

and then iterate in a usual jQuery way:

```
$(objects).each(function() {
    console.log(this.vehTitle) // or whatever you want to do
})
```

If you only need one specific property, you can "pluck" it from the array using this little pythonesque utility function:

```
itemgetter = function(prop) {
    return function() { return this[prop] }
}
```

and then:

```
titles = $(objects).map(itemgetter('vehTitle'))
```

Comment: Thank you - looks interesting.  I will try this tomorrow.  Several new concepts to understand.

Answer (score 1):

`vehs` is an array, containing 3 arrays, each containing an object. So, you'll have to use:

```
for (var i = 0;i<vehs.length;(i=i+1)) {
        $('#selectDIV').append(vehs[i][0].vehTitle + '<br>');
}
```